# Code navigation lost in VScode with Django + Docker

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, cookiecutter-django

I could not find the code definition using `Ctrl + click` when I use `Docker` + `Django` in my project, since source code are now in container. How could I configure my VScode to enable code navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Here is some kind of hack that i am using right now. create a virtual environment.

```
python3 -m venv venv
```

Activate the virtual environment in terminal using

```
source venv/bin/activate
```

now install dependencies from requirements.txt

```
pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```

configure IDE with virtual enviornment. this will give you snippets etc. Now run commands inside the container

```
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py migrate
docker-compose -f local.yml run --rm django python manage.py runserver
```